# calculating an integral with arctg and polynomal

Tags: calculus

I don't know how to calculat this integral, it was on my calculus test and im just curious how to solve it.

$\int \frac {arctanx}{x^3}dx $ = ?

thank you in advane.

Comment: Have you tried integration by parts? Let's say $u=\arctan x$ and $dv=x^{-3}dx$.

Comment: use integration by parts

Comment: I have tried but I got stuck in it. I am doing something wrong cause it is too long.
@MarioG I haven't learned to do it with two u and v together.

Comment: Integration by parts, we can evaluate $\displaystyle{\int{udv}}$ as follows: 
\
$\displaystyle{\int{udv}} = uv-\displaystyle{\int{vdu}}$ where $u$ and $v$ are functions of $x$ and the second integral is easier to calculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrating by parts we have
\begin{align*}
\int{\dfrac{\arctan x}{x^3}dx}&=\int{\underbrace{(\arctan x)}_u\underbrace{(x^{-3}dx)}_{dv}}\\
&=-\frac{1}{2x^2}\arctan x+\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\int{\dfrac{1}{x^2(x^2+1)}dx}}_I...(*)\\
\end{align*}
Where $du=\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx$ and $v=-\frac{1}{2}x^{-2}$. Then, we can evaluate $I$ developing by partial fractions:
\begin{align*}
\int{\dfrac{1}{x^2(x^2+1)}dx}&=\int{\left[\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right]dx}\\
&=\int{x^{-2}dx}-\int{\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx}\\
&=-x^{-1}-\arctan x+c_1
\end{align*}
Then, plugging into $(*)$ we get
$$\int{\dfrac{\arctan x}{x^3}dx}=-\frac{1}{2x^2}\arctan x-\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{2}\arctan x +C.$$

Comment: I get it. Thank you. in the test I actually got until the part of $\int \frac{1}{x^2(x^2+1)}$ and didn't how to develop it.
How for future integrals I will know to develope the fraction? is there any tutorial or something? Thank you.

Comment: There are some integration techiques we can use in order to calculate certain undefined integrals, partial fractions is one of them. Here are some information:
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PartialFractions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Let $u = \arctan x \Rightarrow du = \frac{1}{1 + x^2} dx$ and $dv = \frac{1}{x^3}dx \Rightarrow v = -\frac{1}{2x^2}$

$$\int \frac{\arctan x}{x^3} dx = -\frac{\arctan x}{2x^2} + \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{1 + x^2}\frac{1}{x^2} dx   $$

To evaluate  $\int \frac{1}{(1 + x^2)x^2} dx$ Notice that $\frac{1}{(1 + x^2)x^2} = \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{(1 + x^2)}$.

Can you take it from here?